# move input field

Tags: layout, forms

I have added a new field to the registration form but I am struggling to place it in the correct location. I want to locate it between "Last name" & "Email", its currently below the "sign up for newsletter" checkbox.

How do i do it?

WHAT IVE DONE TO TRY AND RESOLVE MY ISSUE

This field is generated from the data I added to the database so just moving template code  around doesn't appear to be an option.

Looking at the template hints the field is generated by `frontend/customforms/default/template/customer/form/userattributes.phtml` and `frontend/customforms/default/template/customer/form/renderer/text.phtml` and `customer.xml` and the node `<customer_form_template_handle>` removing one will stop the field from being generated.

It would appear making some adjustment to a block would be the answer, maybe by adding it to the local.xml in my custom theme. But what is the best way, do I add all 50 lines  of `<customer_form_template_handle>`?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of attributes for customers and customer addresses. `System` attributes and `User defined` attributes.
The type of the attribute is determined by the flag `is_system` in the `customer_eav_attribute`.
The attributes displayed by the template `customer/form/userattributes.phtml` are the user defined ones (`is_system` = 0).
The other attributes like `name`, `e-mail` and so on need to have an input set manually.
So in order to add a field between last name and e-mail, you must set you new attribute as `is_system` = 1 and then manually put the html markup in the registration form right where you want it.

Comment: I have is_visible set to 1 and the field has been added to `customtheme/areaname/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`. It now shows up between lastname and email, but username is also being displayed below the newsletter checkbox. In addition to this username that I have added to the template is not recognised as a mandatory field